# Will db.createCollection in the following code always set up a new database?

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb

I have the following piece of code in my server.js file in a Node workspace. My question is, every time I run my server.js file from the bash command line, am I setting up a new collection called polls? Or does MongoDb recognize that the collection already exists? What about when I terminate my connection to Mongo and then restart it from the command line?

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener', function(err, newDb){
    if(err){
        throw new Error('Database failed to connect');
    }else{
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDb database');
    }
    db = newDb;
    db.createCollection('polls', {
        autoIndexId: true
    });
});
```

Comment: You've already defined path to the database in the first line: `url-shortener`. ˛`db.createCollection` cannot create new database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db.createCollection` has an option called `strict`, which by default is `false` that will return an error object when set to `true` if the collection already exists. Modify your existing code to have a check to see if the collection with the name `polls` exists, if it already exists then throw out an error.

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener', function(err, newDb){
    if(err){
        throw new Error('Database failed to connect');
    } else{
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDb database');
    }
    db = newDb;
    db.createCollection('polls', {
        autoIndexId: true,
        strict: true
    }, function(err, collection) {
       if(err) {
        //handle error case
       }
    });
});
```

For additional information, you can refer the mongodb nodejs driver documentation at [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/db.html#createCollection) link